# LWC Edit form failing to update

Tags: lightning-web-components

Below code erroring out when i click submit. There is some modal pop message and validation needed before submit . So I need to cancel the default submit. It's failing on  let fields = event.detail.fields;
Please help.

```
   <div class ="slds-card" style="margin-top:-0.5%">   
          
  
     <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name=TLine__c" 
            onsuccess={handleSuccess} onsubmit ={handleSubmit} >
  
     <table class="slds-table_cell-buffer   slds-table_bordered" style ="width:100%" >
         <tbody>
                 <tr>
                      <td >
                                
                     
                                         <label for="fid21">Status</label>
                      <div style="width:70%"><lightning-input-field id="fid21"  field- 
                 name="Status__c" variant="label-hidden" onchange={HandleInlineEdit}> &nbsp; 
          </lightning-input-field>
                                      </div>
                            </td>
                    
                            <td >
                                <label for="fid23">Legal Levy</label>
                             <div style="width:70%"><lightning-input-field id="fid23"  field- 
            name="Date__c" variant="label-hidden" onchange={HandleInlineEdit}> &nbsp; 
       </lightning-input-field>
                             </div>
                             
                            </td>
                                      
                                  
                        </tr>            

          </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="slds-no-flex">
    
            <div if:true ={isEditable} class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="padding:5px;">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" type='submit' onclick= 
   {updateTL}>Save</button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={canceledit}>Cancel</button>  
            </div>
```

Js File

```
import { LightningElement,api,track } from 'lwc';

export default class NXLegalDetailsLWC extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;

   connectedCallback(){
    this.isEdit=false;
}

       handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log('onsubmit: '+ event.detail.fields);

}
handleSuccess(event) {
    const updatedRecord = event.detail.id;
    console.log('onsuccess: ', updatedRecord);
}

updateTL(event){
    event.stopPropagation();

// This must also suppress default submit processing
event.preventDefault();

// Set default values of the new instance.
let fields = event.detail.fields;


// Push the updated fields though for the actual submission itself
this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
 }
```

Comment: I have done similar work and added custom validation code. You can check complete code here: https://newstechnologystuff.com/2020/04/28/lightning-record-edit-form-prepopulate-fields/

Comment: This is awesome. I just started reading it.

Comment: @Tushar Sharma , Basically I want to perform user validation before submitting . This require popup LWC to ask for user confirmation. I can able to perform this popup LWC in different simple parent component. However the modal component is not working with any button click in record-edit-form. Is it possible to invoke modal/popup LWC from lightning record-edit-form at all?

Comment: yes its possible to call it. Check if your experience support the modal

Comment: @Tushar Sharma It worked in simple parent child component. But not in Edit form. I have created another post for it. Can you please help with answer for https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318203/lwc-edit-form-invoking-modal-popup-dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the event handlers defined by `onsuccess={handleSuccess} onsubmit ={handleSubmit}` are the ones that correspond to the success and submit events of the `lightning-record-edit-form`. This means that `e.detail.fields` inside these event handlers will contain all the required information (relevant to the fields).

`button` of `type='submit'` simply invokes the submit event for the `lightning-record-edit-form`. However, the presence of `onclick={updateTL}` in the button HTML overrides the submit event of the record edit form and the `handleSubmit` will never get called. Event object on this `updateTL` has details related to the button itself and nothing related to the record edit form. So, when you execute `e.detail.fields` inside this handler method, nothing is found and you are returned `undefined`.

Remove `onclick={updateTL}` from the button HTML and move the code in `updateTL` into `handleSubmit`. This should solve your error. Also, ensure that the button HTML is placed within record edit form (i.e., before the ending tag `</lightning-record-edit-form>`)

Comment: Appreciate your response. It make sense and worked.